# Bot doesn't deploy on heroku because of requirements.txt

Tags: python, heroku

I was learning Heroku and how to make a discord bot. I made the bot, I tested it and now I need to deploy it on Heroku. The bot has an 8ball command that uses random for choosing a random answer. I added random to requirements.txt, but when I push it I get this error:

```
! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https:(my git)'.
```

It never happened when I only had discord.py there.

My requirements.txt

```
discord.py
random
```

My Procfile

```
worker: python FirstBot.py
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`random` is not a package that you install. It is part of the standard library. Remove it from the requirements.txt.

Comment: When I delete random from requirements.txt 8ball command doesn't work at all

Comment: Why not? What happens?

Comment: It's just doing nothing. I also just realized that none commands work when I deploy them on Heroku, but work when I use my code editor. It's strange, because before that it worked

Comment: apparently, I had to specify discord.py version.., thanks